# FFmpeg blocking pipe until done?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, pipe, popen

I am currently working on a C++ Program (running on Linux) that should run FFmpeg as external Utility to encode the Audio Streams of a Video File to AC3 using `popen()` and capture the Output through the Pipe.

Here is a Sample Code on how I tried to achieve this:

```
int bufferSize = 2048;
char buffer[bufferSize];

FILE *handle = popen("ffmpeg  -i filename.mkv -map 0 -codec:v copy -codec:s copy -codec:a ac3 -f matroska -", "r");
int d = fileno(handle);

while(read(d, buffer, bufferSize) > 0)
{
    // Process Data here
}
```

Actually this works, but not as I expected. The following happens here: FFmpeg starts, encodes the whole file and my program keeps hanging on `read()`. Once FFmpeg is done my program continues and reads the data from the pipe.

But what I actually wanted was to read the output of FFmpeg **while** it's encoding the file. Now I wonder how to make it work that Way? Is FFmpeg blocking the pipe, does not write anything to it until it's done or is my code not capable of reading while the pipe is written? Or is there any argument I need to pass to FFmpeg?

Comment: [ffmpeg probably uses a block buffering mode when redirected](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe). You could try `-progress url` instead.

Comment: Looks like ffmpeg does not block the pipe in all cases. I just noticed the blocking appears only with -map 0 parameter. Once i map each stream individually everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bufferSize changes in the read(...)?
Declaring it as const is a good policy.

Answer (score 0):

Old question to answer but since i just got around to doing this i found it blocks until you read standard error. If you don't clear that then it will not write to standard out.  Took me all of a day to figure that out :-(

Example: i am reading an mp4 and converting to a bitmap stream. After 100 or so frames it just blocked.  Opening a second thread to read standard error gives the following (i add the word Error at begin of line by the way, doesn't mean it's an actual error) and you can see from my snippet it's currently moved well beyond 100 frames.

```
Error frame= 1275 fps=6.8 q=-0.0 size= 3442567kB time=00:00:51.00 bitrate=552970.8kbits/s speed=0.274x
Read bitmap 1280.
Read bitmap 1281.
Read bitmap 1282.
Read bitmap 1283.
Read bitmap 1284.
Read bitmap 1285.
Read bitmap 1286.
Error frame= 1279 fps=6.8 q=-0.0 size= 3453367kB time=00:00:51.16 bitrate=552970.8kbits/s speed=0.274x
Read bitmap 1287.
Read bitmap 1288.
Read bitmap 1289.
Error frame= 1286 fps=6.9 q=-0.0 size= 3472268kB time=00:00:51.44 bitrate=552970.8kbits/s speed=0.274x
Read bitmap 1290.
Read bitmap 1291.
Read bitmap 1292.
Read bitmap 1293.
Read bitmap 1294.
Read bitmap 1295.
Read bitmap 1296.
Read bitmap 1297.
Error frame= 1289 fps=6.8 q=-0.0 size= 3480368kB time=00:00:51.56 bitrate=552970.8kbits/s speed=0.274x
```