# FFmpeg: Is it possible to run block-by-block piped I/O (filtering) of PCM audio data?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm developing a Python FFmpeg wrapper called [ffmpegio](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/index.html) and one feature I want to implement is block-wise avfiltering of raw video and audio data. A block of data is piped to FFmpeg and Python waits for FFmpeg to process and pipe back available output data, rinse and repeat. I've got this to work for video feed but having a trouble with PCM audio I/O. Either PCM encoder or decoder appears to block until the stdin is closed. Is there any way around this behavior?

This question is related to another question ["FFmpeg blocking pipe until done?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028619/ffmpeg-blocking-pipe-until-done) but none of its answers applies (I think)

Edit #1: (deleted a lot of original text for clarity)

Here are minimum Python examples.

First, this is the common script with `load_setup()` to load video and audio data:

```py
def reader(stdout):
    print("reading stdout...")
    y = stdout.read(1)
    print(f"  stdout: read the first byte")
    try:
        stdout.read()
    except:
        pass

def logger(stderr):
    print("log stderr...")
    l = stderr.readline()
    print(f"  stderr: {l.decode('utf8')}")
    while True:
        try:
            l = stderr.readline()
        except:
            break

cmd, x = load_setup() # <- 2 cases: video & audio
nbytes = x.size * x.itemsize

p = sp.Popen(cmd, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

rd = Thread(target=reader, args=(p.stdout, nbytes))
rd.start()
lg = Thread(target=logger, args=(p.stderr,))
lg.start()

try:
    print("written input data to buffer")
    p.stdin.write(x)
    print("written input data")

    sleep(1)
    print("slept 1 second, closing stdin")
finally:
    p.stdin.close()
    print("stdin closed")
    p.stdout.close()
    p.stderr.close()
    rd.join()
    lg.join()
    p.wait()
```

First, rawvideo I/O with the setup function:

```py
def load_setup():
    return (
        "ffmpeg -hide_banner -f rawvideo -s 100x100 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i - -vf 'transpose' -f rawvideo -s 100x100 -",
        np.ones((100, 100, 3), "u1"),
    )
```

which produces the following output:

```
reading stdout...
written input data to buffer
log stderr...
written input data
  stderr: Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':

  stdout: read the first byte
slept 1 second, closing stdin
stdin closed
```

Note that `stderr: ...` and `stdout: ...` appears before `slept 1 second, closing stdin`.

Now, the audio counterpart

```py
def load_setup():
    return (
        "ffmpeg -hide_banner -f f64le -ar 8000 -ac 1 -i - -af lowpass -f f64le -ac 1 -",
        np.ones((16000, 1)),
    )
```

which returns

```
reading stdout...
written input data to bufferlog stderr...

written input data
slept 1 second, closing stdin
stdin closed
  stderr: Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono

  stdout: read the first byte
```

Here, both `stderr` and `stdout` display lines came after `stdin closed`, indicating that FFmpeg only output filtered audio samples after the stdin pipe closure. This behavior persists with different # of samples or with additional `stdin.write()`'s.

So, the question is that is there any workaround to the audio I/O to make it behave like the video I/O. That is, immediately output something following the initial write.

I glanced at `pcm.c` on FFmpeg repo, and it appears the PCM encoder seems to my assertion is incorrect. So I'm looking for a workaround, something simpler than using AVI container.

Edit #2: modified the example to read only the first byte, use different audio filter, and more audio samples

Comment: What is the question? Can you please post a **minimal** reproducible Python code sample that writes and read from FFmpeg sub-process? (`afade` filter doesn't look minimal). How many bytes are in `pcm_s16le` audio "block" and how many bytes are in `pcm_f32le` audio "block"? Can you say something about the subject of FFmpeg buffering? Do you expect to get an output after writing only one "block" of audio?

Comment: @Rotem - You are spot on on what I want to do. I've edited the OP. Thx

Comment: I don't know if there is a way doing it with audio, but with `-af afade` it's not going to work.

Comment: @Rotem - Ok, that's what I was afraid of (I was hoping for a hidden option or something.) But I don't see why `afade` filter not going to work. What's your rationale for that? BTW, I've changed to `lowpass` filter with the same results.

Comment: The audio filter requires few sample before the "filtered sample" and few sample after the  "filtered sample". The audio filter must add latency to the pipeline - there is no option for getting the first output packet right after writing the first input packet. The sequence is going to be: write, write, write..., then read, write, read, write... (I don't now how many audio samples we have to write before the first byte comes out from stdout).

Comment: @Rotem - For `lowpass` I agree of what you described IF the implementation compensates for the group delay of the filter. If it is a simple causal filter, it should output the transient samples as well (so write,read,write,read... all the way). Since I donno how FFmpeg implements `lowpass` so your description could very well be accurate. As for `afade` it should not require future samples to determine how much to fade a particular sample. In any case, I'm fairly confident at this point it's the PCM encoder implementation preventing my intended use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else is curious, I was able to answer my own question running a longer experiment.

(Presumably) the PCM encoder/decoder (used `pcm_f32le` for both) initially buffers its input excessively and the max buffer size appears to be sampling rate dependent. It maxes out at somewhere between 51200 - 52224.

| input S/s | stderr output b/w samples |
| --- | --- |
| 44100 | 51200-52224 |
| 32000 | 51200-52224 |
| 16000 | 32768-33792 |
| 8000 | 16384-17408 |

Once the configuration log is posted on `stderr`, the output floodgate opens and eventually stabilizes to the expected number of output samples per input sample.

Here is a log of repeatedly writing 1024 samples at a time. The filter is `afade` so we expect the same number of output samples. The `stdout` read operation output is read 1024 bytes at a time to a queue on the reader thread and the main thread retrieves blocks with the timeout set to 10 ms.

```
# (block#) - output (#read) samples (unaccounted output samples)
49 - output 3072 samples (49152)
50 - output 9216 samples (40960)
51 - output 10240 samples (31744)
52 - output 5120 samples (27648)
53 - output 5120 samples (23552)
54 - output 6144 samples (18432)
55 - output 5120 samples (14336)
56 - output 10240 samples (5120)
57 - output 4096 samples (2048)
58 - output 1024 samples (2048)
59 - output 1024 samples (2048)
60 - output 1024 samples (2048)
...
934 - output 1024 samples (2048)
935 - output 1024 samples (2048)
936 - output 1024 samples (1536)
937 - output 1024 samples (512)
end - output 512 samples (0)
```

So, it takes 9 main thread cycles to empty the built-up buffer then the filter operation settles with a 2048-byte buffer. Interestingly the buffer size dwindles at the end before the `stdin` is closed, which happened between #`937` and `end`.

@Rotem - Thanks for your exchanges, which allowed me to be formulate the correct experiment.