# Export converted video into stream using ffmpeg pipe option

Tags: .net-core, ffmpeg

I'm stream and successfully output converted video into mkv file.

```
var stream = ..incoming stream of type MemoryStream();
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f mp4 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -s 600:400 -f matroska myfile.mkv";
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(stream.ToArray())
process.BeginOutputReadLine()
process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();
process.WaitForExit(1000);
```

My question is: how can I change the implementation (command and `StandardOutput.BaseStream` in order to export results into memory stream and not file (like it's in the above example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were doing in the just deleted question was correct,

```
-f mp4 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -s 600:400 -f matroska pipe:1
```

let you write the output to a pipe. But you'll likely experience a deadlock because FFmpeg would not read the entire content of `stream.ToArray()` at once. It only reads what it needs to produce the next output data frame.

So, you need to run at least 2 threads on your program, one to write to FFmpeg and another to read from FFmpeg. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with .net so I cannot help you with actual how to, but hopefully this answer points you a right direction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing into right direction

Comment: I just remembered one issue I encountered in [the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70851605). The output could be delayed (you need to input a lot of input frames to produce the first output frame). I think it's specific to PCM audio encoders (never tried matroska) but something to keep in your mind.